# Android- Canvas is not merging images

Tags: android, android-canvas

Can you please tell that what's wrong in the following code?, I want to to display 2 images side by side but resulted bitmap shows only 1 image instead of 2 merged images.

```
int width, height = 0;
        width = UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getWidth()+ UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(1).getWidth();
        height = UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getHeight();

        Log.d("usm_canvasSize","width="+width+" , height="+height);
        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        try {
            Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0), 0f, 0f, null);
            int x = UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getWidth()+ UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(1).getWidth();
            int y = UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getHeight();
            comboImage.drawBitmap(UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(1), x, y, null);

            picture_iv.setImageBitmap(cs);
```

Comment: If you want them side by side, then the `y` is still going to be `0` for the second image, and its `x` will just be the width of the first image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Issue is resolved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitMap is drawn with its top left corner at (x,y). So you should replace calculation of x,y as

```
int x = UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getWidth();
int y = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, for 2 images it's fine but for 3 images i am getting again problem.
    
    'comboImage.drawBitmap(UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0), 0f, 0f, null);
                int x =  (int) (UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getWidth());
comboImage.drawBitmap(UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(1), x, 0, null);

                int x1 =  (int) (UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(0).getWidth()+UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(1).getWidth());
                comboImage.drawBitmap(UploadMorePictures.bitmapsList.get(2), x1, 0, null);'

Comment: Did you increase width while creating bitmap?